# Copying a tuple into multiple groups

Tags: python, tuples

For one of my programs, I want the user to input a color, and then the color gets split up between six faces. I have code like this:
`colors = color, color, color, color, color, color`.
As I'm only working with cubes, this is fine, but if want to create more intensive polygons, with hundreds of sides, this will get quite tedious. My question is, is the a more efficient way to do this?

> color will always be a tuple

I'm aware that you can use the `*` to multiply tuples, but that just makes one long one, not multiple short ones, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: Could you clarify further?  You say colors = (color,)*6 will not work since it generates one long tuple rather than multiple short ones.  But, we have no idea of the requirements for the multiple short ones.  Could you give an example?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the hundreds of colors? If they are hard-coded, there's not a lot you can do, unless there is some pattern (for example, `colors = tuple(x for _ in range(100) for x in ('red', 'blue', 'green'))`.

Comment: The value of the color tuple will look like this: (128,128,128), and I want the colors tuple to look like this: ((128,128,128),(128,128,128),(128,128,128),...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hop that what you want...

```
x = 3  # can be change
color = (1, 2)
colors = [color for i in range(x)]  # colors == [(1, 2),(1, 2),(1, 2)]

# if it must be tuple
colors = tuple((color for i in range(x)))  # faster than convert list to tuple
#  colors == ((1, 2),(1, 2),(1, 2))
```